# Python 2.7 memory error for large complexity

Tags: python, dictionary

i am new to python. I am running the following code and it is giving memory error with python2.7.
Since I am using opencv therefore I am working with python2.7. I have read the previous posts but I am not understanding much from them.

```
s={}
ns={}
ts={}
for i in range(0,256): #for red component
    for j in range(0,256): #for green component
        for k in range(0,256): # for blue component
            s[(i,j,k)]=0
            ns[(i,j,k)]=0
            ts[(i,j,k)]=i*j*k
```

Please help. The code tries to store the frequency of red, green and blue components. And for that I am inititializing these values to zero

Comment: 1)  You're creating about 3*300^3 objects.  2)  Your intention is unclear; why would you want to do this?  3)  You don't inform us of your memory limits; the code *does* exceed 4GB if left unchecked (and I feel it'll go higher than that), but outside of that, I can't derive much else.

Comment: Well, it tries to allocate a lot of memory, that's why. Perhaps you should update the question by telling us what are you trying to accomplish. And someone may come up with a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: Well I am trying to store the frequnecy of red, blue and green components of the pixels.

Comment: I tried run your script for 10 minutes and it eats me 10GB of memory so I have to kill it.

Comment: @Felix: well, yes, look at what it does! Even the inner `range(256)` will construct a 256-element Python list 65536 times. Plus storing all this in a hashtable instead of a flat array. Plus constructing all the distinct tuple objects.

Comment: Hey...look at the answers below...these answers work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thing 1: use `itertools` instead of constructing all the `range` lists each time around the loop. `xrange` will return an iterator object like `range`, and `product` will return an iterator choosing tuples of elements from the given iterable.

Thing 2: use `numpy` for large data. It's a matrix implementation designed for this sort of thing.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from itertools import product
>>> x=np.zeros((256,256,256))
>>> for i, j, k in product(xrange(256), repeat=3):
...     x[i,j,k]= i*j*k
...
```

Takes about five seconds for me, and the expected amount of memory.

```
$ cat /proc/27240/status 
Name:   python
State:  S (sleeping)
...
VmPeak:   420808 kB
VmSize:   289732 kB
```

Note that you may actually run into system-wide memory limits if you try to allocate three 256*256*256 arrays, since each one has about 17 million entries. Fortunately numpy lets you persist arrays to disk.

Have you come across the [PIL (Python Imaging Library)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)? You may find it helpful.

Comment: @JannatArora forgot to mention, if you want an integer array (which will be more memory-efficient) you can do `x=np.zeros((...), dtype=int)`.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, your program needs at least(!) 300*300*300*4*3 bytes solely for the value data of the dicts. Besides, your key tuples occupy 300*300*300*3*3*4 bytes.

This is in total 1296000000 bytes, or 1.2 GiB of data.

This calculation doesn't even include the overhead of maintaining the data in the dict.

So it depends on the amount of memory which your machine has if it fails or not.

You could do a first step and do

```
s = {}
ns = {}
ts = {}
for i in range(0, 300):
    for j in range(0, 300):
        for k in range(0, 300):
            index=(i, j, k)
            s[index]=j
            ns[index]=k
            ts[index]=i*j*k
```

which (in theory) will only occupy half the memory as before - as well, only for the data, as the index tuples are reused.

---

From what you describe (you want a mere counting), you don't need the full range of combinations to be pre-initialized. So you can omit your initialization shown in the question and instead build a storage where you only store these values where you actually have data, which are supposedly much fewer than possible.

You either could use a [`defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) or imitate its behavoiur manually, as I think that most of the combinations are not used in your color "palette".

```
from collections import defaultdict
make0 = lambda: 0
s = defaultdict(make0)
ns = defaultdict(make0)
# what is ts? do you need it?
```

Now you have three `dict`-like objects which can be written to if needed. Then, for every combination of colors which you really have, you can do `s[index] += 1` resp. `ns[index] += 1`.

I don't know about your `ts` - maybe you either can calculate it, or you'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: Thanks a ton...but still it is giving memory error in my program.

Comment: Of course it gives. Every program which needs too much memory gives a `MemoryError`. You should try to reduce the amount of memory needed. I have edited my question in order to show a way for that.

Comment: Thanks a ton...your approach works...but i am not able to set it as the accepted answer...sorry for that

Comment: -1 __Do NOT use a `defaultdict` to simulate a flat array in memory.__ It's just the wrong data structure.

Comment: @katrielalex Thanks for this...but why do u say that it is a wrong data structure

Comment: @katrielalex If you read the requirements, you'll see that the above is only an initialization of a "counting" structure which is supposedly sparse, i.e. only "few" of its places is used ("frequency of colors"). Thus, **it is not a flat array**, not is it intended to be such.

Comment: I'm not sure I read "sparse" out of those requirements. If so then it's at least not wrong -- but I think you should edit your answer to clarify that this is only fast if you don't have many of the rgb tuples.

Comment: @katrielalex I don't think that it is likely to have each and every combination of RGB in a given picture, but only a "few" (thousand) of them. There I see the sparseness and thus the usefulness of my approach. So I edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Even if all your variables used a single byte, that program would need 405 MB of RAM.

You should use compression to store more in limited space.

Edit: If you want to make a histogram in Python, [see this nice example of using the Python Image Library (PIL)](http://tophattaylor.blogspot.com/2009/05/python-rgb-histogram.html). The hard work is done with these 3 lines:

```
import Image
img = Image.open(imagepath)
hist = img.histogram()
```

Comment: The code tries to store the frequency of red, green and blue components of the pixels from images. Since I am new to python...so please suggest a compression technique

Comment: Delta encoding only stores offsets and differences. As you want to store image data, efficient encoding libraries like PIL already exist. Use a lossless format like PNG or TIFF, not JPEG.